# Помогите понять что генерирует openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl

> openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout
>   /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/rsa.key -out /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/local.crt -subj
>   "/C=RU/ST=Minsk/L=Minsk/O=tech/CN=example.local" -config <(cat
>   /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf | sed 's/[ v3_ca ]/[ v3_ca
>   ]\nsubjectAltName = @alternate_names/g' | sed 's/#
>   copy_extensions/copy_extensions/g' | printf "$(cat -)\n[
>   alternate_names ]\nDNS.1 = example.local\nDNS.2 = example1.local")

Comment: хорошо бы научиться правильно писать перевод "Москва" на английский

Comment: :) верно подмечено!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая часть - вызов утилиты для генерирования сертификата с передачей ему кучи параметров. Они определяются текущими потребностями и пожеланиями - к примеру, размер ключа, куда сохранить и тому подобное. Но этой команде нужен конфиг. Его получения я заменил многоточием

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 \
-keyout /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/rsa.key -out /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/local.crt \
-subj "/C=RU/ST=Moskow/L=Moskow/O=tech/CN=example.local" -config <(......)
```

Пойдем дальше, разберем то, что в скобках.

```
# печатаем файл конфига \
cat /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf | \
# делаем замену, а по факту, в секцию [ v3_ca ] дописываем строку \
sed 's/\[ v3_ca \]/\[ v3_ca ]\nsubjectAltName = @alternate_names/g' | \
# опять замена, но по факту - раскомментируем строку
sed 's/# copy_extensions/copy_extensions/g' | \
# печатаем содержимое файла openssl.cnf и дописываем в конец пару строку
printf "$(cat -)\n[ alternate_names ]\nDNS.1 = example.local\nDNS.2 = example1.local"
```

Comment: "для генерирования скрипта" - возможно, не "скрипта", а "сертификата"?

Comment: да да, поправил

Comment: Спасибо! Есть еще вопрос, могу ли я, "ручками" прописать изменения файла openssl.cnf, а затем генерировать сертификат?

Comment: Никто не мешает себе скопировать этот файл и внести в него все нужные изменения. Тогда и команда генерации сильно-сильно упрощается